# Are there computing properties for tetration?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, tetration

If $$2^{2^{2^{2}}}=2^{[2^{(2^{2})}]}=2^{(2^{4})}=2^{16}\;,$$Is it possible to reason any notation properties to make calculations any faster? Or everytime I face a multiplication between iterated powers I'll have to:

1st) Solve them from right to left;

2nd) Multiply like normal exponents;

3rd) Revert the result to the iterated power notation (if there are more multiplications of that sort to be made);

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponential towers must be evaluated from top to bottom (or right to left). Computer programmers refer to this choice as right-associative.
When $a$ and $10$ are coprime, we can compute the last $m$ decimal digits of $^{n}a$ using Euler's theorem.

See this [link](http://www.had2know.com/academics/power-tower-iterated-exponentiation-tetration.html) for computing infinite power towers.

The infinite power tower $x↑↑∞ (\text{or }  ^∞x)$ converges so long as

$e^{-e} < x < e^{1/e}.$

It can be written in closed form using the Lambert W function.

Tetrations can be extended to complex numbers, see [http://www.tetration.org](http://www.tetration.org/)

If you want to compute the tetration in the exponent, [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha) 
has a cool command. For example: 
$$
\text{ Power @@ Table[2, {4}]}
$$

Yields: 
$$
16
$$
As far as I know there are no *computing properties of tetrations* to make calculations any faster. If you want to make calculations faster, I suggest using a computer =(